# Extracting content from the string which has html tag in it in objective-c

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c

I am new to iphone development.I am having a string which has HTML tags in its content.I want to filter the  tag and save the content in another string.

Ex:

```
NSString *HTMLData = @"<h1>Hello this is a test</h1>";
```

I want to filter the header tag and set the content to another string like

```
NSString *actualData=@"hello this is a test" or any string which contain the actual data without HTML tags.
```

Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better Solution:

http://rudis.net/content/2009/01/21/flatten-html-content-ie-strip-tags-cocoaobjective-c

Works For me

Answer (score 1):

http://sugarmaplesoftware.com/25/strip-html-tags/